# how can i show author registration date and time in author profile

Tags: wordpress, author

how can i show author registration date and time in author profile, i want to show author registration date and time in single.php page bio information. without any plugin.

already i tried this tips, but I'm not successfully

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-the-date-a-user-registered?replies=5
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77876/show-user-registration-date-in-wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `the_author_meta` function as so:

```
<?php 
    echo the_author_meta( 'user_registered', 1 ); 
?>
```

..where the first parameter is a string parameter and the second (in this case, 1) is the user id. This is explicit. To be more implicit, you could simply pass the user id in as so. This must be done within the WP loop:

```
<?php 
    $user_ID = $post->post_author;
    echo the_author_meta( 'user_registered', $user_ID ); 
?>
```

If you are using a custom authentication plugin or extension of some sort, you will need to return the id from that object instead. However, it is unclear from your question if that is the case.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this code, It works fine.

```
 <?php
      global $wp_query;
      $registered = date_i18n( "M m, Y", strtotime( get_the_author_meta( 'user_registered', $wp_query->queried_object_id ) ) );
      echo 'Member since ' . $registered;
     ?>
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your answer? Code-only answers are frowned upon on SO.